# Как в Django сформировать sql запрос с двумя переменными

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Есть функция с запросом, которая апдейтит строку в таблице без перезаписи, принимая 2 параметра: **user** и **fly**

```
def enter_fly(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:    
        cursor.execute("UPDATE main_table SET members=members||', '||1 WHERE id = %s",[fly.id])
```

Как правильно вставить **[user.id]** вместо **1**?

**fly.id** работает нормально, в таблице данные добавляются как надо

Возможно есть вариант сделать это через ORM, подскажите как, пробовал что-то типа такого:

```
Fly.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(members="{}, {}".format(Fly.members, 1))
```

но опять же, вместо 1 не получается вставить **user.id**, да и в таблице первым значением массива является  *<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7ff9abd8b3d0>* а дальше через запятую то что я передаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как правильно вставить [user.id] вместо 1?

Используйте f-string.

`cursor.execute(f"UPDATE main_table SET members=members||', '|| {fly.id} WHERE id = %s"`